# Constant message from GarageBand saying "Keyboard shortcuts changed"

Tags: macos, keyboard, garageband, growl

GarageBand constantly fires off the following message when not the foreground app. It's extremely distracting. The messages appear in the Growl dropdown, and continues to cycle between these two messages:

1) **Keyboard shortcuts changed** Australian is not supported - U.S. has been activated.

2) **Keyboard shortcuts changed** U.S. has been activated

Notes:

- Macbook Pro
- OS X 10.9.3
- External Apple keyboard (Australian) and Apple magic mouse
- GarageBand 10.0.2!

[image: img1]
[image: img2]

Comment: that is a new one, so garage band does not support Australia keyboard layout ?

Comment: It does seem that way!